# mute/unmute usb headphone with a Mic

Tags: usb, microphone, headphones, mute

I have a logitech h340 (usb headphones) with no mute/unmute button. I was wondering if there was a command line method to mute and unmute / toggle the Mic on my headphone. I tried:

```
amixer set Capture nocap
amixer set Capture cap
```

and also tried:

```
amixer set Capture toggle
```

Alsa Mixer:

[image]

Comment: Did you get any error with these commands?

Comment: Nope I didn't - it seems to be toggling it:
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]

Comment: I think it's toggling the analog audio ports...but since I'm using a usb headset, i might need to toggle another device. How do i find out?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the command `alsamixer`? Press Alt+PrtScrn then upload it to http://imgur.com

Comment: Thanks, Tim. It's this one:
http://i.imgur.com/jQcJGj7.png

Comment: Hmm it's the same as mine (exactly). Can you use the arrow keys to adjust each one in turn and see if any mute it?

Comment: I tried:
amixer -c 1 sset Mic toggle

This seems to mute it. 

But it seems to be messing with my mouse.
After you toggle, mouse-click seems to be stuck (i.e. when you move your mouse, cursor is stuck at the last point it was in and moving the mouse would highlight the text around it.

Comment: With your mouse!? Wow... How do they connect? Both USB?

Comment: USB yeah. Only when you mute (from System Settings - Sound - (under Microphone Logitech USB Headset H340) or you run that toggle command.

Comment: Try changing the USB ports - do you have a spare one?

Comment: Yeah let me try that.

Comment: Here's what I found: 
http://imgur.com/u8CErZ2

If I mute the first item there "Digital Input (S/PDIF) Logitech USB Headset H340, it doesn't mess with my mouse. 

If I mute the second item there "Microphone Logitech USB Headset H340", it messes up with my mouse. 

I already tried switching usb ports.

Comment: Does muting the first thing work then? If not try these commands `sudo apt-get install xdotool`then `xdotool click 1`. That may get it to reset the click on the mouse...

Comment: Muting the first thing works...but what's the right command line to mute that?

Comment: That way I can set it as a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: That usb mouse conflict might be related to: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1339778

Comment: I don't know the command for that... :/ Does running the xdotool command after the one that broke the mouse work?

Comment: Hmmm it doesn't. :s That's ok.

Comment: Sorry for that...